# Can you recover a mysql database completely from ibdata1, log and frm files?

Tags: mysql, data-recovery

Okay, so bouncing off my other question this morning, we had one of our team members run "sudo chmod 775 /" by accident. It brought down the entire site..

Once I was able to get in, nginx came up without problems. sshd was fixed with a few changes in permissions.. I was even able to create a new database so at least our site can run, albeit with an empty database..

However, I'm now trying to recover our original database. How can I recover with just ibdata1, log files, and frm files?

Comment: Judging from `http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-backup.html` you just copy them to the right place and start the server, you have all the  files you need. If there is a corruption, check the "Forcing InnoDB Recovery" link on that page.

Comment: Actually, it seems the frm files are corrupted somehow.. I don't know why, though.. Can changing the permissions cause corruption somehow?

Comment: With the mentioned command it's doubtful, with 775 as mask and non-recursive (I assume it was recursive). With a different mask some socket communication could have gone wrong or even just writing to the mysql db files. But the database should be recoverable, to the point of the crash/problem.