# Recovering/Rebuilding MySQL .FRM, .MY* files from IBDATA1

Tags: mysql, data-recovery, database-restore

I recently had an incident in which several MySQL files were wiped out (mostly from WordPress, but also a few of MySQL’s own files). The `IBDATA1` file is unaffected, but several `.frm` are gone as are a few `.myi` and `.myd` files.

So now I need to find out if there is a way to rebuild the missing files from `IBDATA1`. I tried Googling it, assuming that such an issue has come up before, and indeed there were numerous search results (including [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/358835/can-you-recover-a-mysql-database-completely-from-ibdata1-log-and-frm-files)), but all of the ones I looked at were the *opposite*, about recovering *from* `.frm` and `.my*` files or somehow required these files.

Is there a way to rebuild these files? I know I have a relatively recent backup (a `.SQL` file) if there isn’t, but I’m hoping that these are the kind of files that are rebuilt if missing or outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to create a new, empty database, imported the last backup, compared the new `.frm`, `.myi`, and `.myd` files to the old ones that were still available, saw that they were identical, and so copied the missing ones. It may not be ideal, but it was simple *enough* and “just works”.